# eclipse juno bold filenames in open resources dropdown

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Eclipse Indigo offered bold filenames in the drop-down list of open resources. A bold filename indicated that the file was open but not an active tab. If I remember correctly, the list of filenames was also sorted alphabetically.

Eclipse Juno by default doesn't bold any of the filenames in this list, and they are also sorted by most recently opened. I assume that the addition quick access search bar had something to do with this.

The quick access bar is a useful new feature; however, is there any way of re-enabling the options for bolded filenames in the drop-down and sorting of resources alphabetically?

Comment: Is this when using Ctrl+3 or Ctrl+E?  It seems to work as expected with Ctrl+3 and the default theme on Windows 7.  Are you specifically talking about Ctrl+E?

Comment: Yes, I was talking specifically about Ctrl+E. Thanks.

Comment: this annoyed me so much, it was one of the biggest reasons why i downgraded to indigo again. seems like I got really used to the sorting over the years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in Juno, still open: [Bug 370441 - Allow to see all editors in ">>" drop-down](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=370441)